# Is it possible, in theory, to take a file, let's say a pdf, created from a tex source file, and convert it to said tex source file

Tags: tex-general

Put another way, is it possible to reverse the work done by the TeX engine? instead of going from source to file, going from file to source?

Comment: no.............

Comment: @Sebastiano you can leave it: I just voted to close based on your comment

Comment: not for arbitrary pdf, but a pdf can theoretically contain enough internal data to recreate a tex-file, e.g. the tex source could be embedded in the pdf.